# .Net Maui - LocationWhenInUse permissions using Windows simulator

Tags: .net-maui

I am making use of the following code:

```
status = await Permissions.RequestAsync<Permissions.LocationWhenInUse>();
```

... before trying to make a call to:

```
Geolocation.Default.GetLocationAsync()
```

... when run using the Windows simulator the following exception was raised:

```
An exception of type 'Microsoft.Maui.ApplicationModel.PermissionException' occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll but was not handled in user code
You need to declare the capability `location` in your AppxManifest.xml file
```

... ok, so I add the following to the file: Platforms\Windows\Package.appxmanifest

```
<Capabilities>
  ...
  <DeviceCapability Name="location"/>
</Capabilities>
```

... run again using the Windows simulator and **status** always returns with a value of **PermissionStatus.Denied**.

According to the [documentation regarding permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/platform-integration/appmodel/permissions?tabs=windows) on Windows  states:

> Permissions must have matching capabilities declared in the package
> manifest. Permission status defaults to Unknown in most instances.

**Question:**

How (and where) does one change the "Permission status defaults"?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the Windows simulator, you need to change the App Permissions / Location settings on your development machine, as follows:

In the Windows taskbar use the Search option and enter "Location".
Select "Location privacy settings" (system settings).   Make the following changes:

[image]

You can also enable or disable Location permissions for your app as shown below:

[image]

When the above settings are changed to an "on" state, calls to Geolocation.Default.GetLocationAsync() will complete successfully.

Hope that helps anyone else as green as me!

**Update: 21-Sep-2022 - another Gotcha!:**

The above will allow Geolocation.Default.GetLocationAsync() to complete successfuly when using the Windows Simulator **ONLY if the request is made on the MainThread** (it works on the Android simulator without having to be on the MainThread).

See [my other post regarding this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73792616/net-maui-windows-simulator-geolocation-default-getlocationasync-raises-exceptio) for further details.